# Update Table Beginning At Record One SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to update a table with records from another table. Whenever I use the insert into statement, I find that the records are simply appended. Instead, I want the records to be inserted from the top of the table. What is the easiest way to do this? I am thin king I could use a update statement, but that means I will have to join the tables. One of the tables(the one I am pulling records from) has only one column. As such, I would have to include another column to do the join.I am trying not to make it so complicated. If there is a simplier way, please let me know.

Sample:

```
Table One
Col1
1
2
3
4

Table 2
Col1  Col2
a
b
c
d
```

I want to move column 1 from table 1 to column 2 in table 2 such that table 2 will be:

```
Table 2
Col1  Col2
a      1
b      2
c      3
d      4
```

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data.  Also remember that SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is no concept of "record one", unless you have another column that specifies the ordering.

Comment: Is it just serendipity that the 1 ends up next to a, 2 next to b?  Or is there some method you're applying?

Comment: There is no relationship between the columns if that is what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you **explicity** define an `ORDER BY` clause in your `SELECT` statements, your result set will be completely arbitrary. This is in line with how any RDBMS should operate. You should consider including a timestamp at the time of insertion to identify the latest rows.

Comment: This is a rather odd choice for an accepted answer.  In my opinion, this "answer" should be a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the update using `row_number()`, but the rows will be assigned in an *indeterminate* order:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t2.*, row_number() over (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from table2 t2
     ),
     t1 as (
      select t1.*, row_numbrer() over (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
     )
update toupdate
    set col2 = t1.col1
    from toupdate join
         t1
         on toupdate.seqnum = t1.seqnum;
```

Note:  if you have an ordering in mind, then use the appropriate `order by` in the partition clauses.

Comment: Based on sample data in OP, I'd say order both row_numbers() by Col1.